# Using setState in separate BottomNotifcationBar class back to the main class

Tags: dart, flutter

If I keep the bottomNotificationBar in the same class as the rest of the page, setState works properly and the buttons work properly.

If I move the bottomNotificationBar to another class, I cannot get the setState to work, because it needs to reference back to the main class.  I've tried a few things, but I can't wrap my mind around this yet.

The error is:
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
setState() called in constructor:

The part that isn't working is marked near the bottom of this:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(new MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          title: 'My Title',
          home: new MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }


    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
    }


    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      var selectedPageIndex = 0;
      var pages = [ Page1(), Page2(), ];

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: pages[selectedPageIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar:
              MyClass().buildBottomNavigationBar(selectedPageIndex),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyClass {
      BottomNavigationBar buildBottomNavigationBar(selectedPageIndex) {
        return new BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: Text("Page1"),
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: Text("Page2"),
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            ),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {

/////////////////////////////START OF SECTION///////////////////////////
            _MyHomePageState().setState(() {
              selectedPageIndex = index;
            });
/////////////////////////////END OF SECTION///////////////////////////

          },
          currentIndex: selectedPageIndex,
        );
      }
    }
```

--------------EDIT:----------------

Ok, now I have the following code below, and I am getting the following 2 things:

info: 
The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'.

exception:
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'setState' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: setState(Closure: () => Null)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Title',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  static void setIndex(BuildContext context, int _newIndex) {
    _MyHomePageState state = context.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher<_MyHomePageState>());
    state.setState(() {
      state.selectedPageIndex =_newIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectedPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(),
      bottomNavigationBar:
          MyClass().buildBottomNavigationBar(context,selectedPageIndex),
    );
  }
}

class MyClass {
  BottomNavigationBar buildBottomNavigationBar(context,selectedPageIndex) {
    return new BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          title: Text("Page1"),
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          title: Text("Page2"),
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        ),
      ],
      onTap: (index) {
    MyHomePage.setIndex(context, index);
    },
      currentIndex: selectedPageIndex,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you Require is `CallBAck` Function from the other class. As `setState`  has to be called on object -`_MyHomePageState`.

With `Class Constructors` we pass the initial Data & got a Callback on `SetState()`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Title',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectedPageIndex = 0;
  var pages = [
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: pages[selectedPageIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: MyClass(
        selectedPageIndex: selectedPageIndex,
        myFunc: _myFunc,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _myFunc(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }
}

class MyClass extends StatelessWidget {
  MyClass({this.selectedPageIndex, this.myFunc});
  final int selectedPageIndex;
  final Function myFunc;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          title: Text("Page1"),
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          title: Text("Page2"),
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        ),
      ],
      onTap: (index) {
/////////////////////////////START OF SECTION///////////////////////////
        myFunc(index);
/////////////////////////////END OF SECTION///////////////////////////
      },
      currentIndex: selectedPageIndex,
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text('1'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Container(child: Text('3'),));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your `MyHomePage` by adding a `static` method into it so its state can be called from anywhere:

```
  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  static void setIndex(BuildContext context, int _newIndex) {
  _MyHomePageState state = context.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher<_MyHomePageState>());
    state.setState(() {
      state.selectedPageIndex =_newIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
  }
```

Then when you want to change the `index` call:

```
  onTap (index) {
    MyHomePage.setIndex(context, index);
  }
```

Comment: I'm so sorry I mixed some code .. I have corrected it

Comment: I'm getting "The method 'setState' was called on null".  So, a couple of clarifications on your code:  There should be a colon after onTap: correct? So that I put it in the onTap part of the BottomNavigationBar section in place of the onTap: that is in my code above.  Also, in order to use "context" there, I had to add "context" to ` MyClass().buildBottomNavigationBar(context,selectedPageIndex) ` and to   ` BottomNavigationBar buildBottomNavigationBar(context,selectedPageIndex) { `

Comment: Also, I am getting this info, not an error, I don't know if this is important or not:  info: The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'

Comment: let me look into the issue

Comment: by the way did you tried the solution after I edited it ?

Comment: Yes, I used your edited solution.  See my edited question above, at the end, to see my current code exactly as is.